# Unable to mount memory cgroup

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, mount, cgroups

I'm attempting to mount the memory cgroup with the following command:

`sudo mount -t cgroup none /sys/fs/cgroup/memory -o memory`

I get the error:

`mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on none, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

I have all the cgroup kernel configuration options enabled and can mount the cpu, cpuset and devices cgroups without issue.

What am I missing?

**Operating System:** Raspberry Pi OS Lite (64-bit)

**Kernel Version:** 5.10.95

Comment: Just to confirm, can you check that the memory cgroup is enabled in runtime? It can be checked with `cat /proc/cgroups | column -t`

Comment: The memory cgroup was not enabled. I enabled it in /boot/cmdline.txt and rebooted. The cgroup is now enabled in /proc/cgroups, but when I attempt to mount I get `mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/memory: cgroup already mounted on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu.`

When I check `mount | grep cgroup` only cpu is mounted to /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu.

Comment: There is an existing cgroup mount which I did not configure. I'm not sure if it's causing an issue or how to disable it if it is: `cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)`

Comment: cgroupv2 can be disabled with the kernel commandline flag `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0`.

Comment: Perfect. Enabling memory cgroups and disabling cgroupv2 in the kernel commandline file with `cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` resolved all my issues. Thank you so much. If you submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling memory cgroups and disabling cgroupv2 in the kernel commandline file with `cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of additional details to [Jaese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/667424/jaese)'s answer that put me on track for resolving a similar cgroup problem that I was having in docker.

You will need to add the following kernel command line options:

```
cgroup_enable=memory 
systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0
```

In a clean Debian 11 (bullseye) install, the `cgroup_enable=memory` option was already set.

To do this in practice, you need to modify the bootloader configuration. The steps to do this may vary depending on your Linux distribution and the bootloader being used. In particular check out if your systems used GRUB2 (Ubuntu, Debian, Centos, Fedora, and others) or `systemd-boot` (Arch Linux, Fedora, and Clear Linux):

For GRUB2 on Debian do the following:

1. Edit the file `/etc/default/grub`  and find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Add the following options to the end of the line, inside the quotes: `cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0`.
   It should look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="... cgroup_enable=memory systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0"
```

2. Update the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

3. Reboot the system for the changes to take effect.

Note that this also solves errors such as:

- `Missing file or directory` inside the cgroup tree (e.g. `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/` or `/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct/`), or
- `Failed to reset control group /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/...: Device or resource busy`.