# docker-compose permission error "Can not mount memory cgroup. Probably cgroup support is missing from running kernel. Unable to continue."

Tags: linux, docker-compose

I'm new to docker and trying to get three services up: domjudge, mariaDB and judgehost (don't think their purposes are relevant). The problem is when I try to run them, judgehost's status is "Exit 1", which means an error (while the other's are "up"). Looks like a permission-related error.

Inside the "dockered" directory, I run the following commands:

`sudo docker-compose up -d`

Which seems to start the three services just fine.

`sudo docker-compose ps`

Which shows the following output:

```
Name                    Command               State                 Ports         
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
judgehost_domserver_1   /scripts/start.sh         Up (unhealthy)   0.0.0.0:12346-         
                                                                   >80/tcp,:::12346-      
                                                                   >80/tcp                
judgehost_judgehost_1   /usr/bin/dumb-init --     Exit 1                                  
                        /scr ...                                                          
judgehost_mariadb_1     docker-entrypoint.sh      Up               3306/tcp               
                        --max ...
```

´docker-compose logs´

Which output I highlight this part:

```
[..] Setting up cgroups
judgehost_1  | mkdir: cannot create directory '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset': Read-only file system
judgehost_1  | mount: /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/: mount point does not exist.
judgehost_1  | Error: Can not mount cpuset cgroup. Probably cgroup support is missing from running kernel. Unable to continue.
judgehost_1  | 
judgehost_1  |             To fix this, please make the following changes:
judgehost_1  |             1. In /etc/default/grub, add 'cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1' to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT
judgehost_1  |             2. Run update-grub
judgehost_1  |             3. Reboot
```

I obviously tried to follow the instructions, but the problem persists. Also tried to run the commands with and without sudo, and running the mkdir's manually, error logs are still the same.

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04 (kernel version 6.2.0-27-generic) in a Galaxy Book 2 (i3-1215U × 8).

EDIT: Solved! Putting the flag `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=0` on the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` of the file `/etc/default/grub` solved the problem. Found the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965770/unable-to-mount-memory-cgroup) associated post.